# How to set default value for data class

Tags: android, kotlin

I create a data binding for my fragment.

```
// fragment_my
<layout ...>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="myData"
            type="com.example.myproject.MyData" />
    </data>

    ...
</layout>

// MyFragment
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMyBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_my, container, false
        )
        Log.d(TAG, ${binding.myData.item})
        return binding.root
    }
}

// MyData
data class MyData(
    var item: String = "123"
)
```

But when I run my project, it show the item not init correctly and it always return an optional nullable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the data before accessing/using it.

**Try this:**

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
    inflater, R.layout.fragment_my, container, false
)
binding.myData = MyData()
Log.d(TAG, ${binding.myData.item})
return binding.root
```

**binding.myData = MyData()** is missing in your code.

*Source*: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#binding_data